# mysql returns no rows but all off words is available on sql and DB

Tags: mysql

My database is:

```
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `oc_artists_tags` (
  `artists_tag_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `artist_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `artist_tag` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`artists_tag_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=203 ;

INSERT INTO `oc_artists_tags` (`artists_tag_id`, `artist_id`, `artist_tag`) VALUES
(1, 113, 'ke$ha'),
(2, 113, 'kesha'),
(3, 113, 'keshha'),
(4, 113, 'ke'),
(5, 113, 'ha');
```

And my sql is:

```
SELECT * FROM `oc_artists_tags` 
WHERE `artist_tag` LIKE '%ke$ha%' 
  AND `artist_tag` LIKE '%kesha%' 
  AND `artist_tag` LIKE '%keshha%' 
  AND `artist_tag` LIKE '%ke%' 
  AND `artist_tag` LIKE '%ha%'
```

When I run this code I got this:

```
MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0005 sec)**
```

Why? Where is the problem?

Comment: `OR`, `OR`, `OR` Because `artist_tag` cannot the all of these things at the same time but it can be `'%ke$ha%' ` OR `'%kesha%'` etc etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `OR` the predicates:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `oc_artists_tags` 
WHERE `artist_tag` LIKE '%ke$ha%' OR 
      `artist_tag` LIKE '%kesha%' OR
      `artist_tag` LIKE '%keshha%' OR 
      `artist_tag` LIKE '%ke%' OR 
      `artist_tag` LIKE '%ha%'
```

By using `AND` is like saying: get me the records having a tag like `ke$ha` **and** like `kesha`, etc.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/54944/2)

Comment: No my sql is true. There are 5 records.

Comment: @DilaraAliyeva Yes, but none of them matches **all** of the strings you specify in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Yes I got it! Thank you!

Comment: @DilaraAliyeva The sql of my query is returning all records the match **any** of the strings specified in the `WHERE` clause.